# Ruby string concatenation add space

Tags: ruby, methods

I need to make a method that repeats a given word but I think I am designing it wrong. I need spaces between the words, what am I missing here?

```
def repeat(word, repeats=2)
  sentence = word.to_s * repeats
  return sentence
end
```

Comment: Get over yourself with the down vote. Even if it is a seemingly simple question there's value in different ways of solving a problem, or giving someone a chance to teach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you are missing spaces.

You could have done it like this:

```
def repeat(word, repeats = 2)
  Array.new(repeats, word).join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Also, slightly shorter but unsure if it’s more/less readable: `([word] * repeats).join(' ')`

Comment: Even shorter: `([word] * repeats) * ' '`

Comment: Why create a temporal array with a single element and build on top of that when you can do all that in one step? Unless you are doing golf, counting in terms of token makes more sense than counting the bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the code as below :

```
def repeat(word, repeats=2)
  ([word] * repeats).join(" ")
end

repeat("Hello",4)
# => "Hello Hello Hello Hello"
```

Comment: This, I believe, is the direction I was headed. I had `def repeat(word,repeats=2)
  sentence = word.to_s * repeats
  return sentence.join(" ")
end`  but after seeing this, that seems silly and I can see why it's so wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one closer to your approach and without using a temporary array:

```
def repeat(word, repeats=2)
  ("#{word} " * repeats).chop
end
```

- `"#{word} "` converts word to a string using string interpolation and appends a space
- `… * repeats` creates a string containing *repeats* copies
- `.chop` returns the string with the last character removed (the trailing space)

Not having to create an array makes the code a bit faster.

Comment: So if you do it thousands of times you can save a fraction of a second? Who cares?

Comment: The point is that you don't have to create a temporary array, having faster code is a nice side effect.

Comment: But you went way out of your way to benchmark it, as if speed is the important metric. It's not.

Comment: @sawa *Returns a new String with the last character removed* - exactly what I want in this case. IMO neither `chomp!(" ")` nor `[0..-2]` is cleaner or prettier.

Answer (score 0):

```
w = 'kokot'
n = 13
n.times.map { w.each_char.to_a.shuffle.join }.tap { |a, _| a.capitalize! }.join(' ') << ?.
```